# loading xml from a database to be used in multiple functions

Tags: php, xml, javascript

I have a database where i'm using php to randomize the information by ID and send it out via xml.  My issue is that I only want to grab the xml once and store it for use in at least 2 functions... one function that runs onload to grab the first line of xml, another that will run every time a button is pressed to access the next line of xml until the end.  My 2 functions are loadfirst() and loadnext().  loadfirst() works perfectly, but I'm not sure how to pass the xml data to loadnext().  Right now I'm just using loadfirst() on pageload and loadfirst() on button press, but i end up creating new xml from the database each time which causes randomization issues and is incredibly inefficient.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
var places;
var i = 0;

function loadXML(){

downloadUrl("places.php", function(data){
    places = data.responseXML;
        getFeatured(i);
});



}

function getFeatured(index){
   var id = places[index].getAttribute("id");
    var name = places[index].getAttribute("name");
    var location = places[index].getAttribute("location");
    var imgpath = places[index].getAttribute("imgpath");
    var tags = places[index].getAttribute("tags");

}


    function getPrev() {
    i--;
    getFeatured(i);
}

 function getNext() {
    i++;
         getFeatured(i);
    }


function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
     var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
        }
     };
     request.open('GET', url, true);
     request.send(null);
   }

    function doNothing() {}
```

loadnext() will be very similar to loadfirst(), I'm just running into issues with passing the xml data so that i can use it without having to access the database again.  Thanks.

Comment: You don't know how to find that "next"? Or what is wrong withloadnext() ?

Comment: i only want to store the xml data once and then use it in multiple functions.  So, I need to figure out how to load the xml in loadfirst() and then access it whenever i want in whatever function i want, in this case loadnext(), without having to go back to the database and generate new xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `xml`  and `i` in public scope. Then all you have to do is increment/decrement i and re-read data from XML.  Something like this:

```
var xml;
var xml_idx = 0; // replaces your i counter

function loadXML() {
    downloadUrl ("places.php", function(data) {
        xml = data.responseXML;
    )};
}

function loadItem(index) {
    var id = xml[index].getAttribute("id");
    var name = xml[index].getAttribute("name");
    var location = xml[index].getAttribute("location");
    var imgpath = xml[index].getAttribute("imgpath");
    var tags = xml[index].getAttribute("tags");
    // do something with this data
}

function loadCurrentItem() {
    loadItem(xml_idx);
}

function loadNextItem() {
    xml_idx++;
    loadItem(xml_idx);
}

function loadPreviousItem() {
    xml_idx--;
    loadItem(xml_idx);
}

// usage
loadXML();  // do this first to populate xml variable
loadItem(xml_idx); // loads first item (i=0)
loadCurrentItem(); // loads i=0
loadNextItem(); // loads i=1
loadNextItem(); // loads i=2
loadPreviousItem(); // loads i=1
```

If you really want to get fancy (and keep the global namespace cleaner), you could easily make this into a class.

Comment: question?  where are you coming up with items[index] in loadItem()?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated all of them to `xml` now, which is what they should be.

Comment: Note, I also changed counter from `i` to `xml_idx` as it would probably be a very bad idea to rely on `i` not being used elsewhere in other javascript code.

Comment: question?  where are you coming up with items[index] in loadItem()?  Also, I'm showing that xml is undefined but it's declared in global scope as you indicated.  original question code updated.

Comment: I changed teh `items` to correct `xml` in code.  `xml` will be `undefined` until you perform `loadXML()` and a value gets set for it. Note I didn't your `downloadURL()` function in my example as that part didn't need any changing.  That function is still referenced in my example though.

Comment: I did notice that.  would you mind browsing my code once more to see if there are any issues?  Notice the alert(places) once in getFeatured().  It shows up as undefined still.

Comment: Have you actually called the `loadXML` function anywhere?

Comment: oh yes, sorry.  <body onload="loadXML()">.  could there be a load time issue?  the database isn't very large at the moment, but it will end up being very large.

Comment: You would likley need to put `getFeatured(i)` in the `loadXML()` function within the callback function, directly after `places = data.responseXML;`  This is because the loading of the XML takes place asynchronously. Right now, your `getFeatured(i)` is likely being executed before the AJAX call is completed. Also, defintely change you index variable name from `i` to something else since `i` is so commonly used in other javascript code. You don't want your global variable being overwritten.

Comment: placing getFeatured(i) within downloadUrl got rid of that issue, however, we're still looking at some undefined variable.  Cannot call method "getAttribute" of undefined.  I'm guessing that it's talking about "i"  I will change the index variable once everything else is working properly.  thanks.  updated code again.

Comment: It also looks like you are missing a `}` a the end of `getFeatured()` function declaration.

Comment: You should be specific about which line of code is giving you the javascript errors.

Comment: var id = places[index].getAttribute("id"); - uncaught type error:  cannot call method getAttribute of undefined.

Comment: Have you verified that the actual server request/response was OK in the AJAX?

Comment: yes.  it generates the xml fine and when i alert (places) it has data. in my watch expressions in the javascript console it shows "i" has undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Use global variables (items - items array, iterator - counter) to store data available for all functions.
Try something like this:

```
items = false;
iterator = 0;

function loadfirst(){

downloadUrl ("places.php", function(data) {
    var i = 0;
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var places = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("place");
    var id = places[i].getAttribute("id");
    var name = places[i].getAttribute("name");
    var location = places[i].getAttribute("location");
    var imgpath = places[i].getAttribute("imgpath");
    var tags = places[i].getAttribute("tags");

    items = places;
    iterator++;
)};
}


function loadnext(){


    var i = iterator;
    var id = items[i].getAttribute("id");
    var name = items[i].getAttribute("name");
    var location = items[i].getAttribute("location");
    var imgpath = items[i].getAttribute("imgpath");
    var tags = items[i].getAttribute("tags");

    iterator++;

}
```

Comment: do i need to use downloadUrl in loadnext()?  I'm trying to avoid accessing the database more than once for this task.

Comment: No, you do not need. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap all this into a single object to control scope and data state. (Untested code below, which should just illustrate a possible pattern and interface to use.)

```
function PlacesScroller(url, callback) {
    this.url = url;
    this.data = null;
    this._index = null;
    this.length = 0;
    var self = this;
    downloadURL(this.url, function(result, status) {
        if (Math.floor(status/100)===2) {
            self.setData(result);
        }
        if (callback) {
            callback(self, result);
        }
    });
}
PlacesScroller.prototype.setData(xmldom) {
    this._index = 0;
    // this may require changing; it depends on your xml structure
    this.data = [];
    var places = xmldom.getElementsByTagName('place');
    for (var i=0; i<places.length; i++) {
        this.data.push({
            id : places[i].getAttribute('id'),
            name : places[i].getAttribute('name')
            // etc
        });
    }
}
PlacesScroller.prototype.getPlaceByIndex = function(index) {
    if (this.data) {
        return this.data[index];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
PlacesScroller.prototype.getCurrentFeature = function() {
    return this.getPlaceByIndex(this._index);
}
PlacesScroller.prototype.addToIndex(i) {
   // This sets the index forward or back
   // being careful not to fall off the end of the data
   // You can change this to (e.g.) cycle instead
   if (this.data===null) {
        return null;
   }
   var newi = i+this._index;
   newi = Math.min(newi, this.data.length);
   newi = Math.max(0, newi);
   this._index = newi;
   return this._index;
}
PlacesScroller.prototype.getNextFeature = function() {
    this.addToIndex(1);
    return this.getCurrentFeature();
}
PlacesScroller.prototype.getPreviousFeature = function() {
    this.addToIndex(-1);
    return this.getCurrentFeature();
}
```

Then initialize it and use it like so:

```
var scroller = new PlacesScroller('places.php', function(scrollerobject, xmlresult){
   // put any initialization code for your HTML here, so it can build after
   // the scrollerobject gets its data.
   // You can also register event handlers here

   myNextButton.onclick = function(e){
        var placedata = scrollerobject.getNextFeature();
        myPictureDisplayingThing.update(placedata);
   }
   // etc
});
```